# Prove submultiplicativity property for this matrix norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

If I am given $Y\in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ is nonsingular and a matrix norm defined as $\|A\|_Y = \|Y^{-1}AY\|_2$, how do I show that it has the property:  $$\|AB\|_Y \leq \|A\|_Y\|B\|_Y$$

At first I was thinking that $ \|Y^{-1}AY\|_2$ is equal to the max singular value of $A$ because it looks like a similarity transform; however, I don't think that is valid.

Comment: Do you already have submultiplicativity for the $2$-norm?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Note that\begin{align}
\|AB\|_Y &= \|Y^{-1}ABY\|_2\\
&=\|(Y^{-1}AY)(Y^{-1}BY)\|_2
\end{align}

Try to complete it using submultiplicative property.